# Hinges have come loose from particle-board cupboard

Tags: hinges, particle-board

I have a large number of built-in cupboards made from laminated particle board (called chipboard here in Australia), with doors attached with two or three cabinet hinges each.

Either the previous owner liked to swing on the doors, or the cupboards weren't of high quality, because there are three or four hinges around the home where the chipboard has given way, and and the hinge has come loose from the side of the cupboard.

I am trying to decide whether to move the hinges up or down a small amount and reinstall (leaving holes in the chipboard), or whether I can just use polyfilla (or similar) to patch over holes and re-drill them.

Neither sounds pretty, but it is hidden from public view so I am not too fussed about the appearance.

Is polyfilla a disaster waiting to happen or a reasonable approach? Is there a third option?

Comment: The term you're looking for is [Particle board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_board)

Comment: Thanks, @Tester101. Apparently the term "chipboard" is used mainly in UK and Australia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with an epoxy filler rather than a cellulose based product. You've already got chipboard, and you need all the additional strength you can get. Drill the old holes out to a size larger than the screws, including thread. Fill the holes with a 2 part epoxy and let dry. Level the surface as needed, then drill pilot holes for the screws into the epoxy. Screw the hinges back on.